# Shapeless: How to express <: case class type param for Generix.Aux

Tags: scala, shapeless

I've got the following code to basically iterate through the fields of a `case class` and map them using a `Poly` to the same type and use `ToList[HL, Out]`

For simplicity we can assume the `Poly` does this:

```
object Schema extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseInt = at[Int](_ => "I'm an int")
  implicit def caseString = at[String](_ => "Oh boy a string")
}

def infer[V1 <: Product, Out <: HList, MapperOut <: HList](v1: V1)(
  implicit gen: Generic.Aux[V1, Out],
    map: Mapper.Aux[Schema.type, Out, MapperOut],
    to: ToList[MapperOut, String]
): List[String] = to (gen to v1 map Schema)
```

This is all very straightforward and works very well for simple scenarios:

```
case class Test(id: Int, text: String)
val list = infer(Test(2, "text"))
// List("I'm an int", "Oh boy a string")
```

Now going out to where the buses don't run:

```
class Automagical[T <: Product with Serializable : TypeTag] {
  def instance: T 
  // The typetag bit is needed for something else
  def convert: List[String] = infer(instance)
}
```

Sadly any call to above fails with:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.Generic.Aux[T,Out]
```

**Bonus**

How can I improve the `infer` method by not requiring an instance of `T` at all? Obviously type inference is fine, but I do need to somehow materialise a `List[String]` from an `HList[Lub]` and map over something.

Given I only ever care about the types, is it possible to derive a concrete instance of `List[String]` by only knowing the types to be poly mapped encoded as an `HList?`

Something like:

```
 def infer[V1 <: Product, Out <: HList, MapperOut <: HList]()(
  implicit gen: Generic.Aux[V1, Out],
    map: Mapper.Aux[Schema.type, Out, MapperOut],
    to: ToList[MapperOut, String]
): List[String] = {
  // Magically build an HList with samples from its types.
  // Or an alternative approach that gives the same outcome
  val reifiedInstance = reify[Out]
  to (reifiedInstance map Schema)
}
```

Comment: The `Automagical` trait doesn't compile for me: "traits cannot have type parameters with context bounds", but of course the error you mentioned occurs with an abstract class as well.

Comment: @devkat My mistake, that was a class in the original implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that `convert` has access to the implicit parameters for `infer`, they have to be present when the `Automagical` instance is created:

```scala
abstract class Automagical[T <: Product with Serializable : TypeTag,
    Out <: HList, MapperOut <: HList]
  (implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[T, Out],
    map: Mapper.Aux[Schema.type, Out, MapperOut],
    to: ToList[MapperOut, String]) {
  def instance: T
  // The typetag bit is needed for something else
  def convert: List[String] = infer(instance)
}
```

Comment: That would make it a no go in my case, as I need `Automagical` to be a typeclass.

Comment: I accepted the answer as it solves that particular problem. Is there any way to deal with the not needing the instance thing that you know of?

Comment: scalacheck-shapeless (https://github.com/alexarchambault/scalacheck-shapeless) can create sample instances for case classes, probably via `HLists`. Maybe it is worth checking out how it is done there.